# carpentry/ beam question

Tags: carpentry

i just recently open a wall in my basement but there is a post on the center of the wall that Im contemplating on removing. So, my idea was to apply a steel plate to the side of the beam and some adjustable post on each side of the beam, ill take any input on this thanks

Answer (score 8):

When contemplating removing structural supports where removal improperly might destroy your house, the only sensible path is to hire an engineer to assess what a suitable structurally sound replacement for the support you want to remove is.

Otherwise, leave the post in place.